# What happens to a web method call if I close the connection early?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET 2.0 Smart client and with web service back end that I am working with.  Currently, there are a few asynchronous web service calls made by the client which can take up to 30 or so seconds to complete.  The web service calls do not return any data (we are actually pushing data up to our central SQL server).  Right now, everything works fine, but I am figuring out all of the edge cases and wondering what happens with the web service if the client application is closed between call and completion.  Has anyone had this situation before, and if so, what is the proper way to handle it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have code checking for:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected
```

Then it'll continue to execute.

Comment: and if the webservice calls on the backend are truly asynchronous, you could check for this property every 1 or 2 seconds and abort the calls if client is not connected anymore and that way stop wasting resources.

Comment: Well, thats the thing - I want to allow the web service to finish processing and at the same time allow the users to exit the application if they wish without affecting the long running operation.